# Binding checkbox to an ScrollBar.Visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to bind `scrollBarVisibility` with `checkBox` property `IsChecked`.
If `IsChecked` is true `scrollBarVisibility` need to be Visible.

XAML:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <local:Nustatymai x:Key="checkBox_keitejas" />
</Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
<!-- ..... -->
<ScrollViewer Name="tempimas" IsEnabled="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
              Height="795" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=check1, 
              Converter={StaticResource checkBox_keitejas}}" >
</ScrollViewer>
<!-- ..... -->
<WrapPanel>
     <TextBlock>Rodyti apatini scrollBar</TextBlock>
     <CheckBox Name="check1" IsChecked="True"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

C#:

```
class Nustatymai : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((bool)value == true)
            return ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
        else
            return ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

> For now this code is not working for me and I need your help to solve it!

Comment: Scroll bar does not show/hide or content can still be scrolled even though scroll bar is not visible?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need converter to do this. You can use DataTrigger:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="tempimas" IsEnabled="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
              Height="100">
                <ScrollViewer.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=check1, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ScrollViewer.Style>
            </ScrollViewer>
            <WrapPanel>
                <TextBlock>Rodyti apatini scrollBar</TextBlock>
                <CheckBox Name="check1" IsChecked="True"/>
            </WrapPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually works,I think you have an issue with the height of the scrollviewer. please check it with the window height.